# c#.net mandar un mensaje de felicitacion en el dia de nacimiento

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, ado.net

Buenas tardes espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:

En mi entidad donde tengo todos los datos de la tabla tengo estos dos.

```
 public DateTime Fecha_nacimiento { get; set; }
 public bool Felicitacion { get; set; }
```

para la parte donde hago mi condicion.

```
public string FelitarmeCumple(EntAmigos a)
        {
            DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now.Date;
            //if(Convert.ToDateTime(existe.Rows[0]["Fecha_nacimiento"]) == DateTime.Now){
            if (a.Felicitacion && a.Fecha_nacimiento.Month == hoy.Month && a.Fecha_nacimiento.Day == hoy.Day)
            {
                throw new Exception("¡Feliz Cumpleaños!");
                //feliz = a.Felicitacion.ToString();
            }
            return $"{a.Fecha_nacimiento}";

        }
```

y lo mando a llamar en mi controller donde se encuentra mi tabla de amigos, el conexionAmigos es lo que ocupo para utilizar lo que tengo en esa parte que seria ahi donde se encuentra mi condicion de arriba. La lista es donde llamo mis datos de obtener para mi tabla.

```
 public ActionResult Pagina1(EntAmigos a, EntUsuario u)
        {
            try
            {
                //EntUsuario usu = conexionUsuario.ValidarUsuario(u);
                //Session["EntUsuario"] = usu;

                List<EntAmigos> ls = conexionAmigos.ObtenerAmigos(a);
                
                TempData["feliz"] = conexionAmigos.FelitarmeCumple(a);
                TempData["contador"] = conexionAmigos.CantidadRegistros();
                return View(ls);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["error"] = ex.Message;
                List<EntAmigos> ls = new List<EntAmigos>();
                return View(ls);
            }
        }
```

y en mi html solo lo llamo normal como un dato de la tabla.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr  title="id:@item.Id_Amigo">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreCompleto)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Edad)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha_nacimiento)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Foto)
            </td>
           <td>
                <div style=" text-align:right">
                    @if (TempData["feliz"] != null)
                    {
                        <h3 style="color:black; text-align:right; font-size:18px;"> @TempData["feliz"]</h3>
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
```

Solo que no me muestra nada , no se que es lo que coloque mal.Espero me puedan orientar.

Comment: Si pones un punto de interrupción antes de llamar a la visa, y verificas los datos dentro de `ls`, sabes si trae algún elemento?

Comment: no me permite poner punto , o no se si yo no pude, y los datos de mi ls agarran normal , solo la parte donde pongo el bool de felicitacion no manda a llamar nada

Comment: MessageBox.Show no es una funcion de asp.net.. es una funcion de vb para apliaciones de escritorio...

Comment: Todo el codigo que mostras se ejecuta en el servidor... donde esperas que aparezca ese messagebox? en el cliente?? entonces necesitas un alert de js....

Comment: si de hecho la quite y puse un throw new exception pero no me marca la fecha de nacimiento correctamente